Flutter: Scrolling to a widget in ScrollView IN A PageView
Simiular to Flutter: Scrolling to a widget in ListView
But with one crucial difference:
My SingleChildScrollView is a children from a PageView above. And here is the problem:
When I use the approach with the DataKey (and a ScrollController). It is scrolled in the vertical, the current widget AND the horizontal, the PageView. This looks very buggy and is of course not intentional. It should only be scrolled in the current widget, to the said container.
Code:
class _Widget1 extends State<Widget1State> {
  final PageController otherController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 5,
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: otherController,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          Widget2(otherController: otherController,),
    //...
    

class _Widget2 extends State<Widget2> {

  final dataKey =  GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
    //Also tried with a controller, didn't change anything.
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
    //...
     Container(
              key:  dataKey, //Here i want it to scroll
    //...
     TextButton(
                      
                        onPressed: () {
       
                          Scrollable.ensureVisible(dataKey.currentContext!); //Approach to start scrolling
                        },
                        child: Text(//....

As I said, now its scrolling Vertical and Horizontal
Any fixes, ideas, workarounds?

Can you share with dartPad

It's an intended behavior for Scrollable.ensureVisible method, as the doc mentioned, and I quote "If the Scrollable of the provided BuildContext is a TwoDimensionalScrollable, both vertical and horizontal axes will ensure the target is made visible.".
one way to work around is to calculate the actual pixels you need to scroll, and scroll with the controller.

the problem with the actual pixel is: It is depent on the screen size then, isn't it? @ming chen

@FabianM what about getting the screen size from the context, e.g. MediaQuery.of(context).size ?
